# Condition to check if the user is in the model and to block before re-enrolling

Tags: python, django

Hi I have a problem with writing a condition that checks if the logged in user is currently on the list of enrolled users and blocks him from re-enrolling, and if he is on the list, it unlocks my access to the tournament transition.

this is my views.py file

```
def groups(request, pk):
    tournament_groups = get_object_or_404(TournamentGroup, pk=pk)
    tournament_users = TournamentUsers.objects.filter(user_group=tournament_groups)
    judges = TournamentJudges.objects.filter(user_tournament=tournament_groups.tournament_name)
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(tournament_name=tournament_groups.tournament_name)
    form = TournamentUsersForm()
    current_user = request.user.debatants
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = TournamentUsersForm(
            initial={'user_tournament': tournament_groups.tournament_name,
                     'user_group': tournament_groups,
                     'user_full_name': current_user})
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TournamentUsersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = TournamentUsersForm()

    context = {'tournament_groups': tournament_groups,
               'tournament_users': tournament_users,
               'form': form, 'judges': judges,
               "tournament": tournament,
               'current_user': current_user,}
    return render(request, 'ksm_app2/groups.html', context)
```

this is my models.py file

```
class TournamentUsers(models.Model):
    user_full_name = models.ForeignKey(Debatants, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user_tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user_group = models.ForeignKey(TournamentGroup, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_full_name.id)
```

this is my template

```
       {% for tournament_user in tournament_users %}
            {% if current_user.id == tournament_user.user_full_name.id %}
                <h2>Jesteś już zapisany</h2>
            {% else %}
                <h2>Zapisz się jako uczestnik</h2>
                <form method="post" style="visibility: hidden"><br>
                    <button type="submit" style="visibility: visible!important">Zapisz się</button>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <label for="name">Imię i nazwisko</label>
                    {{ form.user_full_name }}
                    <label for="tournament">Wybierz turniej</label>
                    {{ form.user_tournament }}
                    <br>
                    <label for="tournament">Wybierz drużyne</label>
                    {{ form.user_group }}
                    <br>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

I tried to write a condition in html template but I don't know how I can check if for example logged user's id is in the model, the only thing I did at this point what doesn't work correctly was to write a loop for all users and their id and compare them to logged user's id. The loop doesn't work correctly because it agrees only when there is only one user with whom it agrees for the other one, it already gives a fake. Would anyone be able to tell how I can fix it.
I would appreciate any advice

Comment: inside your template tournament_users forloop if you add `<h1>{{ tournament_user.user_full_name.id }}</h1>` inside your forloop so what is the output you are getting?

Comment: id of current user which is logged in

Comment: can you please send me any one id of this code `<h1>{{ tournament_user.user_full_name.id }}</h1>`

Comment: ```<h1>{{ tournament_user.user_full_name.id }}</h1>``` = 47

Comment: what's the output of this one? `{{ current_user.id }}`

Comment: 47 too, but this is in for loop so only one return true then always return false